# css image gallery with inner zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a working inner-zoomable image using the code below and I would like to modify this to an image gallery with zoom of the selected image element, but cannot figure out how to begin. What I would like is for the image source in the second hyperlink below ("img_02" src=") to substitute for the first. Anyone shed any light please?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <img id="zoom_01" src="../images/package.jpg"  data-zoom-image="../images/package_big.jpg">
       <img id="zoom_01" src="../images/package.jpg"  data-zoom-image="../images/package_big.jpg">    
       <div id="zoom_01">
              <a href="#" data-image="../images/package.jpg" data-zoom-image="../images/package_big.jpg">
              <img id="img_01" src="../images/package_thumb.jpg" /></a>

              <a href="#" data-image="../images/coffee.jpg" data-zoom-image="../images/coffee_big.jpg">
              <img id="img_02" src="../images/coffee_thumb.jpg" /></a>
       </div>

<!--initiate the plugin and pass the id of the div containing gallery images-->

<script>
$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({zoomType: "inner", cursor: "crosshair",}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by gallery you mean like the one showed here: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Comment: Did you try following the documentation? http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#gallery-lightbox

Comment: More or less Imran, and yes Leo, I did, but I have not managed to make their 'gallery and lightbox' work. As I already have the basic inner zoom working (and understand why it does), I'd like to try extending the image source to a gallery with selectable elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) ID should never be used more then once in a single html ~ you have used "zoom_01" 3 times use it only on the first image.

2) To create a gallery you should use this code:

```
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true, loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'});
```

Here is the fixed HTML:

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="../images/package.jpg"  data-zoom-image="../images/package_big.jpg">
<div id="gallery">
      <a href="../images/package_big.jpg" data-image="../images/package.jpg" data-zoom-image="../images/package_big.jpg">
      <img id="img_01" src="../images/package_thumb.jpg" /></a>

      <a href="../images/coffee_big.jpg" data-image="../images/coffee.jpg" data-zoom-image="../images/coffee_big.jpg">
      <img id="img_02" src="../images/coffee_thumb.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

And yes the demo site HTMl code is wrong :) ~ i will send them a mail.

Comment: I have already indicated that I followed the example and cannot get it to work, so simply referring me back there does not add anything. I have made my question more specific, showing where I am at, in the hope that someone else can help. What I would like is for the image source in the second hyperlink above ("img_02") to substitute for the first.

Comment: I have changed my answer, update your code and let me know if this solves the problem!

Comment: The code now works Imran, thanks. One question: the gallery links are js-based and do not function if javascript is disabled or blocked. I don't mind if zooming is inactive under such circumstance, but the links to the images must remain live. I'm looking into this now, and if you can advise further that would be appreciated

Comment: I have updated the code .... i have added image url to href attribute which will work in case JS is diabled

Comment: Thanks Imran, but I was looking more for a way for the links to activate in the 'window' of src_01; Adding path details to the href simply opens up that image and navigates away from the page -- undesired behaviour. In any event, you answered my original question so perhaps this should be another, separate question. Thanks again.